# Flash - что можно узнать о пользователе?

Tags: flash, вконтакте

Вопрос интересует, какие данные можно получить от пользователя из Flash приложения? Например, браузер, ОС, версию флешки... возможно?

Comment: Всё, что можно флешем, естественно, можно и флеш-приложением.

Comment: А что можно флешом?

Comment: Версию точно можно. Кроме того, если речь идет о вконтакте (судя по тегу), то из flashVars можно кое-что выудить (см. документацию вконтакта).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Информация незначительна, но версию флеш-плеера и ОС узнать можно: класс [flash.system.Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/system/Capabilities.html)

Свойства:

- os: String - Указывает текущую операционную систему;
- version: String - Показывает сведения о платформе и версии Flash Player или Adobe® AIR;
- screenResolutionX(Y): Number - Задает максимальное разрешение экрана по горизонтали(вертикали);

Ну и ещё несколько. Если использовать ещё и javascript и ExternalInterface, то узнать получится побольше=) Хотя бы строку user-agent. Где браузер, ОС и, иногда, разные довески написаны.

Comment: Жаль, что браузер не узнать.